# Where can I get browser use data broken down by country?

Tags: browser

I've seen plenty of sites that provide data on which browsers and versions of those browsers are most popular on the web today, but I'm curious about whether certain countries are more enriched in a specific browser than others.  I am on a project now, and the PM seems to think that IE6 is the most prevalent platform in the parts of corporate India that are likely to use this site.  I have no reason to really doubt that, but I was mostly just curious if there are data available to back that up.  Do different countries really have different browser use tendencies?

---

EDIT:  Thanks to Dan F. for the great link.  It shows that IE6 is by far the main browser in India.  Can someone enlighten me as to why it's so tremendously different than the U.S. IE6/7 ratio?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/) does breakdowns by region

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Indeed, India's IE6/IE7 ratio is completely different from that in the U.S.  Wild.

Comment: No worries. It sure is wacky. Bear in mind that statcounter's stats are only as good as the sites that have its tracking bug. It's not absolute gospel, but it's better than hand waving guesses :-)

Comment: @Chris. That's because corporate IT here mostly lock down the OS for personal software installation by the user. Another reason i find is most of the internal corporate sites work better in IE6 only.IT follow a policy like if it's not broken then don't fix. They still believe that IE6 is the most powerful, secure browser in earth. I hate them.

Comment: StatCounter now also have browser maps!
http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201209-201209-map

Answer (score 5):

The [statcounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-IN-weekly-200904-200913) site says IE6 is the leader for the last 8 weeks in India.

You can select a country or a region, and see their stats.