# IE6 weirdness -- first list item indented too far

Tags: css, internet-explorer

CSS is not my strong suit, and I am not sure what's going on with my list items in IE6.  I want them to align vertically, but the first list item is always being pushed a pixel or two two far to the right, so it no longer lines up with the other members in the list.  As far as I'm concerned, this list looks fine in IE7/8, FF3, and Chrome 2 (all on Windows).

Here's what it looks like in IE6... note that Vangala's entry is improperly indented:

[alt text http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/8123/ie6liindent.png](http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/8123/ie6liindent.png)

Here is my relevant CSS:

```
.organizer-label {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
}

.organizer-value {
    margin-left: 150px;
}

.organizer-value ul {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}
```

Here is my relevant html:

```
<div class="organizer-subsection">
  <div class="organizer-label">Committee members:</div>
  <div class="organizer-value">
    <ul>
      <li>Vangala Subrahmanyam, Sai Advantium Pharma Ltd, Pune, India</li>
      <li>Ramaswamy Iyer, Bristol-Myers Squibb, Lawrenceville, USA</li>
      <li>Ragu Ramanathan, Bristol-Myers Squibb</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I doing something stupid and just getting lucky that it looks okay in most browsers?  What can I do to make the list line up correctly in IE6?

Comment: The cascading nature of CSS makes it a tricky beast.

I'd suggest first trying to explicitly define rules for *all* the properties of the elements in question i.e. not just rules for the ul, but for the li also. And not just left and top margins and padding, but bottom and right too. And indent rules, line heights, borders, display and so on.

Try being explicit about absolutely everything to rule out some odd rule leaking through where you don't expect it.

I'm adding this as a comment not an answer as I don't know if it will fix the problem but may help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: The question is, should you really care about IE6? 

http://ajaxian.com/archives/i-wont-support-ie-6-in-2009

Comment: Yeah, I have to care.  Sadly.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054351/where-can-i-get-browser-use-data-broken-down-by-country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply [hasLayout](http://haslayout.net/) to the div `.organizer-value`

```
.organizer-value {
    margin-left: 150px;
    zoom:1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a float bug. You can step around it by nesting the **ul** inside a wrapper **div** like so;

```
<div class="organizer-subsection">
  <div class="organizer-label">Committee members:</div>
  <div class="organizer-value">
    <div>
       <ul>
          <li>Vangala Subrahmanyam, Sai Advantium Pharma Ltd, Pune, India</li>
          <li>Ramaswamy Iyer, Bristol-Myers Squibb, Lawrenceville, USA</li>
          <li>Ragu Ramanathan, Bristol-Myers Squibb</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and changing the .organizer-value definition to this;

```
.organizer-value {
    float:left;
}
```

Floats are evil in IE (as is anything remotely useful that CSS does). The plus side of such common bugs is that they are fairly well documented. [PositionIsEverything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/) is a useful website for helping troubleshoot IE display bugs.

Comment: I was going to post my own answer, but since you're already linking to PIE, maybe you can include a link to its description of this specific problem. It's the 3-pixel text-jog: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/threepxtest.html.

Comment: I didn't link because I didn't know what the bug was called, I just figured it out and posted a fix. :) The PIE link was just for future ref! +1 for the exact link though, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some nastiness in your CSS. If I've got this right, and I hope that I have, you are looking to have the committee members list just to the right of the title 'Committee members'

With IE6 I tend to avoid using margins where possible as there are some fun and interesting bugs there for the unwary developer.

The following may help you out, but I can't honestly say what it will do to the rest of your page.

```
.organizer-label {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
}

.organizer-value {
    padding-left: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.organizer-value ul {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}
```

Hope that this helps

R.

Answer (score 0):

try it ".organizer-value { overflow:hidden;float:left;}"

Hope that this helps

Answer (score 0):

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611/ie6-to-support-or-not-to-support) here on SO, people reference the [IE7-js library](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). It's supposed to make IE6 behave like a standards compliant browser.This might also fix your spacing problem